# Error with \begin{equation} and \end{equation}

Tags: errors

I am writing a document on writelatex.com and I get an error with this:

```
\begin{equation}

[any text here returns an error]

\end{equation}
```

The error message is

> Display math should end with $$.

I don't undestand this and I can't understand what the problem is, I have other documents when this code works fine. Is it possible that I'm missing some package?

Comment: If you download the source code, does it compile in you local LaTeX install? Or, if you don't have LaTeX installed, just paste the code into the question, please.

Comment: @Sid Well, a [Minimal (non-)Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) is strongly prefered :)

Comment: @Herbert Thanks a lot Herbert, that was exactly the problem.

Comment: @tohecz Sorry that I deleted my comment before you answered. I would have posted a MNWE here but this problem was so small that I didn't want to go through that trouble. And now it's been resolved. Next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the environment does no like empty lines. Put a `%` before such lines or delete them.

```
\begin{equation}
%
[any text here returns an error]
%
\end{equation}
```

or

```
\begin{equation}
[any text here returns an error]
\end{equation}
```