# Why does pdflatex fail with newline in equation source?

Tags: math-mode, equations, tex-core

I recently encountered behavior I've never seen before.

This compiles fine:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    f = x
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

But this fails:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    f = x

\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Why does pdflatex care about a newline inside the equation environment?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error with \begin{equation} and \end{equation}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158948/error-with-beginequation-and-endequation)

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos that question does fix the problem, but it doesn't answer the question. I'm more after what reasoning caused this to be the way the compiler (or tex specificiation, whichever) should behave.

Comment: It is an assumption in TeX that math will not cross a paragraph boundary, so a paragraph break (`\par` or a blank line) is considered an error.  It is easy to forget to end math whether inline or display, so trapping and reporting this condition is a quick and easy way to locate errors.

Answer (score 2):

The primitive syntax is much more terse `$$ .... $$` and if you forget the closing `$$` it  would destroy the document. So by giving an error at end of paragraph it gives TeX a chance to limit the scope of the error and recover with normal text at the next paragraph.